# PHP fails to chmod?

Tags: php, unix, ubuntu, file-permissions, chmod

I'm running PHP 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2 (with `safe_mode` = `Off`) and I'm unable to correctly set the mode for any file or directory from within a PHP script, I coded the following test (just to make sure):

```
$result = array();

if (mkdir('./I/do/not/exist/', 0777, true) === true)
{
    $result['./I/'] = sprintf('%s (%s)', getFileOwner('./I/'), getFilePermissions('./I/'));
    $result['./I/do/'] = sprintf('%s (%s)', getFileOwner('./I/do/'), getFilePermissions('./I/do/'));
    $result['./I/do/not/'] = sprintf('%s (%s)', getFileOwner('./I/do/not/'), getFilePermissions('./I/do/not/'));
    $result['./I/do/not/exist/'] = sprintf('%s (%s)', getFileOwner('./I/do/not/exist/'), getFilePermissions('./I/do/not/exist/'));
    $result[__DIR__] = sprintf('%s (%s)', getFileOwner(__DIR__), getFilePermissions(__DIR__));
    $result[__FILE__] = sprintf('%s (%s)', getFileOwner(__FILE__), getFilePermissions(__FILE__));
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';

function getFileOwner($path)
{
    $user = posix_getpwuid(fileowner($path));
    $group = posix_getgrgid(filegroup($path));

    return implode(':', array($user['name'], $group['name']));
}

function getFilePermissions($path)
{
    return substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($path)), -4);
}
```

And this is the output:

```
Array
(
    [./I/] => www-data:www-data (0755)
    [./I/do/] => www-data:www-data (0755)
    [./I/do/not/] => www-data:www-data (0755)
    [./I/do/not/exist/] => www-data:www-data (0755)
    [/home/alix/Server/_] => alix:alix (0777)
    [/home/alix/Server/_/chmod.php] => alix:alix (0644)
)
```

Why do none of the (sub-)folders of `./I/do/not/exist/` get the specified (`0777`) permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have to clear the [umask](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php) first before creating the directory. However it is recommended to adjust the permissions using chmod instead of relying on umask.

Comment: Thank you, I actually had no idea what the `umask` was, but now I get it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have umask 022. Try to add `umask(0)` before `mkdir`

Answer (score 1):

[Just read the manual:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

> The mode is also modified by the current umask, which you can change using [umask()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php).

Check your systems [umask](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php) and make use of the mode parameter accordingly.

Alternatively set the umask to a value you're able to deal with.

Or take care of [chmod'ding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) *after* the creation of the directory.