# folders created with php, are being owned by apache

Tags: php, apache, chown

We are using a linux dedicated server in our company.

Whenever we create a folder with php script, apache is owning the folder and each time I have to connect to server via root in order to change the owner to the user and the permissions

But I don't know which setting I should change in order to fix this.

I tried to switch the safe mode on/off but it didn't work.

I'd be glad if someone could help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: what FTP / File program are you using?

Comment: You can use chmod() after create folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a portability issue and depends on your server configuration (i.e. mod_php or FCGI with SuExec).

You can try using the `chown` function right after you created the file, but that will only work if you know who the actual owner should be (which is not always the case). To overcome this issue, [I wrote a simple method](https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/blob/558431470922be267be2758051bb6ee4df8eb8fc/phunction/Disk.php#L16) that tries to find the best possible file mode that always assures reading and writing (as well as execution for directories) without giving excessive permissions:

```
function xChmod($path, $chmod = null) // adapted from phunction
{
    if (file_exists($path) === true)
    {
        if (is_null($chmod) === true)
        {
            $chmod = (is_dir($path) === true) ? 777 : 666;

            if (extension_loaded('posix') === true)
            {
                $user = posix_getpwuid(posix_getuid());

                if (array_key_exists('name', $user) === true)
                {
                    $chmod -= (in_array($user['name'], explode('|', 'apache|httpd|nobody|system|webdaemon|www|www-data')) === true) ? 0 : 22;
                }

            }
        }

        return chmod($path, octdec(intval($chmod)));
    }

    return false;
}
```

Basically, if you omit the second `$chmod` argument, it will use `0777` for folders and `0666` for files by default, however, if PHP is being run under a non-standard user, it will decrement the mode by 22, yielding `0755` for folders and `0644` for files. Bare in mind that this will only work for files that already exist, so if you're creating a directory [you'll need to have additional precautions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6839786/89771).

Comment: It doesn't change the owner to the user I want but it makes the folder writable, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using the [chown PHP command](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php) and [chmod PHP command](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)?

Answer (score 2):

There are **2** ways to do this:

`chown()` where you can change the file permissions via executing that function.

or if you are able to move files around using an FTP, you can drag the file outside of the document root (`public_html/`), and right click -> change file permissions on the file.

CHMODs are what you want to be looking at. `777` will give anyone and everything access to your file, which you can use as a test to make sure you have file permissions. I don't recommend keeping the permissions on `777` at all though.